# I am looking for a way to get an invald users not to logged on in the same way as not exist users

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am using Laravel 6 , looking for a way not to logged on in the same way as not existing users on the login screen.

I added a certain column to the users table that created by the default user-auth function.

the column type is "boolean". its name is "valid".

when a user who has a false "valid" column tries to log in, then I would like to get the login screen to say "the user does not exist."

login.blade.php

```
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
```

When an Invalid user try to login ,  I would like to put "This account is invalid " to $message and display it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the directives to check the state of user's `valid`. Something like this.

```
if (Auth::user()->valid) return redirect("yourAfterLoginRoute");
return redirect("yourFailAfterLoginRoute");
```

Comment: I don't think that would work since OP wants a check to happen before the user has logged in, and at that point, I believe `Auth::user()` will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your LoginController.

```
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        $arr = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
        $arr['valid'] = true;
        return $arr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with [Laravel Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware).

> Middleware provide a convenient mechanism for inspecting and filtering
> HTTP requests entering your application. For example, Laravel includes
> a middleware that verifies the user of your application is
> authenticated. If the user is not authenticated, the middleware will
> redirect the user to your application's login screen. However, if the
> user is authenticated, the middleware will allow the request to
> proceed further into the application.

Well, You could set up a middleware to be responsible for revoking/redirecting *"invalid users"*.

Below are a few steps to point you in the suggested direction.

#### STEP 1

Generate the middleware: `php artisan make:middleware RevokeInvalidUser`

You will find the middleware in `App\Http\Middleware` directory.

#### STEP 2

Add your logic for revoking/redirecting *"invalid users"* in the new middleware's `handle` method.

```php
// RevokeInvalidUser middleware.

<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Models\User;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RevokeInvalidUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (
            ($request->method() === "POST")
            && ($request->path() === "login")
            && ($user = User::firstWhere("email", $request->email))
            && !$user->valid
        ) {
            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->with(["acInvalidMessage" => "This account is invalid."])
                ->withErrors([
                    "email" => "The user does not exist."
                ]);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

#### STEP 3

Register your middleware in the `protected $middlewareGroups` array of  `App\Http\Kernel.php` class file.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    // ...

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            // ...
            
            \App\Http\Middleware\RevokeInvalidUser::class,
        ],
        
    // ...  

}
```

#### STEP 4

*Demo*: For accessing the *"This account is invalid"* message in **views**, make this small tweak:

```php
// Instead of:
<strong>{{ $message }}</strong> ❌

// Use this:
<strong>{{ session()->get('acInvalidMessage') ?? "" }}</strong> ✅
```

#### Addendum

*NOTE: Anything below only applies if you don't have the *"valid"* column already.*

In case you haven't created/added the column labelled "valid" on the `users` table, you can create it by running a migration. i.e:

1. Add the migration by running the command below in your terminal.

`php artisan make:migration add_valid_column_on_users_table`

2. Open the migration file found in `your-project-root-directory/database/migrations`. Edit it with the relevant lines of code.

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddValidColumnOnUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table("users", function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean("valid")->after("email")->default(true);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

3. Run your recently created migration against the database with the command below.

`php artisan migrate`

4. Test the implementation by invalidating some users. (*changing a specific user's "valid" database column value to 0 on the users table.*)

Comment: I have the same problem.
And I tried your answer.

Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Mon May 17 13:35:54 2021] home check=>
[Mon May 17 13:35:54 2021] home check=>
[Mon May 17 13:35:54 2021] home check=>
[Mon May 17 13:35:54 2021] home check=>



*
but it seem to cause an infinite loop.*

Comment: @conny, Do you already have a column named _"**valid**"_ created on the user's table similar to what the OP described in his/her question?